# Using CiviRule to delay tax receipts

Tags: civirules, cdn-tax-receipts

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I could use a CiviRule to delay sending the tax receipts by email?  For our gala, we need to wait until we know the exact non-deductible portion of each ticket before we send the receipt so I'd like to set up a rule to delay the automatic tax receipt email.

My alternative was to set the financial type to non-deductible for now, then go back after the event and set it to deductible and then process the receipts.

TIA!

Answer (score 1):

Are you using CDN Tax Receipts extension? You can turn off automatic sending of tax receipts in Admin - CiviContribute - CDN Tax Receipts with the Attach receipts to automated workflow messages? option. Then you can process them manually whenever you like (note this applies to all contributions, so you'll need to process the tax receipts manually for all donations until you turn it back on).

If you do the non-deductible to deductible switcheroo, watch out because the non-deductible amount will be set to the full amount of the donation, so you need to make sure you set each one manually.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up - I don't want to turn off for all donations, so I guess I will have to switch and manually update!

Answer (score 0):

Do I understand correctly that the non-deductible amount of the related contribution is not filled in initially but is filled once the percentage is known?

If that is the case you could create a rule with "contribution changed" as trigger and use  the "field value comparison" condition to check if the non-deductible amount is filled in?

And probably also add the contact to a group (temporary until the whole process is done) so you can check if the contact is not in the group yet (to avoid sending more times). Does that make sense?

Comment: In theory yes I could use that to send the correct tax receipt that includes the non-deductible amount, but I also need a way to not automatically send the tax receipts when the contribution is initially entered

Comment: I do not get it? That would be the trigger "contibution is added" while my suggestion uses the "contribution is changed"? So how would the tax receipt be sent when the contribution is entered? Or am I missing something?